# Does Akamai have a rest client

Tags: akamai

When a request comes in Akamai, if there isn't a specific cookie, I would like to call a REST service in order to set that cookie right from within Akamai, then Akamai should route the request towards to right farm for serving the request or serve it from the cache.

So the question is does Akamai have a rest client?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of requests on the Akamai *edge* proxy is defined using your configuration.

If you want programatic behavior on the Akamai proxy, something like

```
if (!exists(specificCookie)) { 
     var cookie = executeRESTService()
     request.setCookie(cookie)
}
```

then what you probably want is an [Edge Worker](https://www.slideshare.net/Akamaidev/edgeworkers-enabling-autonomous-developer-friendly-programming-at-the-edge).

Comment: Can you set up a database connection in an edge worker (to mongo atlas for example)?

Comment: Mongo Atlas is available as a REST service: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/
You can communicate with REST API services from an Edgeworker. See https://techdocs.akamai.com/edgeworkers/docs/http-request